# Windows 7 request admin credentials for device installation

Tags: windows-7, drivers, group-policy

When opening administrative tools on win7 I get a credentials dialog.
I want to get the same dialog when trying to install drivers for plug-n-play hardware that was just inserted.

How can this be done?

Disclaimer: I don't want to disable specific devices, and actually not disable any device, but merely prevent someone else connecting a removable device when I'm not in front of the computer and my user is logged on.

Comment: This can be done by using a group policy to prevent unauthorized USB devices from even being recognized by Windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Block USB access, but allow only specific ones (in particular, one USB mass storage device)](https://superuser.com/questions/1226252/block-usb-access-but-allow-only-specific-ones-in-particular-one-usb-mass-stor)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, because there are devices I do want to install drivers for, but only when I enter my credentials.

Comment: You can do that by only making mounted volumes accessible by Administrator

Comment: @Ramhound How can I do that?