# Allow only a specific USB device

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, security

I was wondering if there was a way to secure the transfer of data from a computer to another by USB (one that should not be accessed by anything else than this USB drive).

So a way to allow a specific USB drive to transfer some information on a computer. I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1226252/block-usb-access-but-allow-only-specific-ones-in-particular-one-usb-mass-stor) however it still doesn't seem secured enough since the same USB device from the same manufacturer might go through the protection. 
Maybe there is a way to program the USB key as well ?

Thank you in advance for your answer.

P.S : the system is on Windows 7 Embedded.

Comment: Why does it need to be USB? There are many other ways to transfer data more securely from one computer to another without USB

Comment: @EricF It needs to be USB because it's an HMI that only has a usb port and no wifi or internet connexion

Answer (score 0):

We had a customer with the same request.

Also using Windows Embedded 7.

I used this software
https://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbdlm_help_e.html#getting_started

> USBDLM is a Windows service that gives control over Window's drive letter assignment.
>
> -ask the user for a password before he can use a drive.
>
> -assign a letter from a list of new default letters, also dependent on many different criteria as the active user, drive type, type of connection (USB, FireWire), USB port, volume label, size, user and others.

You are able to give access only to specific stick, even down to serial number, but i choosed the password protection.

This still works if the stick gets lost or damaged.
Only a privileged user at the customer (and of course our service) knows the password.

Comment: Thank you for this, I will check this software !